# How to deserialize a Vec<SocketAddr>

Tags: rust, serde

I currently deserialize a JSON array into `Vec<String>` and down stream in my application I convert individual `String` to `SocketAddr`.

I would like to do the deserialiation into `Vec<SocketAddr>` with serde instead.

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Doc {
    // It would be nice to have Vec<SocketAddr> instead
    hosts: Vec<String>
}

fn main(){
    let data = r#"
        {"hosts": ["localhost:8000","localhost:8001"]}
    "#;
    let doc: Doc = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    dbg!(doc);
}
```

Comment: localhost is not an ip

Comment: serde supports deserializing `SocketAddr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to disagree with the other two answers: You can absolutely deserialize strings like `"localhost:80"` to a (Vec of) `SocketAddr`. But you absolutely shouldn't. Let me explain:

Your problem is that `SocketAddr` only holds an IP address + port, not hostnames. You can solve this by resolving hostnames into `SockAddr` through `ToSocketAddrs` (and then flattening the result because one hostname can resolve to multiple addrs):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Doc {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "flatten_resolve_addrs")]
    hosts: Vec<SocketAddr>,
}

fn flatten_resolve_addrs<'de, D>(de: D) -> Result<Vec<SocketAddr>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    // Being a little lazy here about allocations and error handling.
    // Because again, you shouldn't do this.
    let unresolved = Vec::<String>::deserialize(de)?;
    let mut resolved = vec![];
    for a in unresolved {
        let a = a
            .to_socket_addrs()
            .map_err(|e| serde::de::Error::custom(e))?;
        for a in a {
            resolved.push(a);
        }
    }                                                                                      panic!("You really shouldn't. Go read my Stackoverflow answer.");
    Ok(resolved)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7a051be6604d50cab4aa3b4d206fcb8f)

You shouldn't do this because, deserialization should really round-trip through serialization, and be a pure function of the input bytes, but resolving addresses may access the network. Problems are:

- What's the retry logic when resolution fails?
- If your code is long running, the resolution result might change (from dns load balancing, dynamic dns, network config changes, …), but you can't re-resolve the addresses.
- If your code is started as a system service, it might fail to start up with a deserialization error if the network isn't fully configured yet.
- If a connection to one of the specified addresses fails, you have no way of printing a nice error message with the target hostname.
- How would you configure a default port for this?

(Doing these things wrong is a pet peeve of mine, you'll find it in nginx, Kubernetes, Zookeeper, …)

Personally, I'd probably keep the `Vec<String>` for simplicity reasons, but you might also choose to do something like deserializing to `Vec<(Either<IpAddr, Box<str>>, Option<u16>)>` so you can check whether the strings are valid addresses, but do things like hostname resolution and providing a default port when you connect to those addresses.

Comment: Great answer! Absolutely correct, in every way. Tbh I was a little too lazy for the full version, and I yield to your answer ;)

Comment: 100% clean would probably be to implement a `HostnameAndPort` struct that holds all valid hostname+port combinations, to represent the input directly. Which can the be used to look up an actual address later; but at least you will be sure that your input is a valid hostname+port during deserialization.

Comment: That's the part I was too lazy for ;) (hence the dodgery with `Either`). Might also want to implement a `fn to_sockaddrs(&[HostnameAndPort]) -> impl ToSocketAddrs` or so so you can easily hand your struct to `connect`.

Answer (score 2):

Serde supports deserializing to `SocketAddr`, but your input isn't able to be parsed because `localhost` is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.

The input needs to be a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address for it to deserialize directly into a `SocketAddr`. If you have control over your input data, this would work:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr, SocketAddrV4, ToSocketAddrs};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Doc {
    hosts: Vec<SocketAddr>,
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#"
        {"hosts": ["127.0.0.1:8000","127.0.0.1:8001"]}
    "#;
    let doc: Doc = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    dbg!(doc);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
[src/main.rs:15] doc = Doc {
    hosts: [
        127.0.0.1:8000,
        127.0.0.1:8001,
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize into `SocketAddr` directly, no extra work required:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Doc {
    // It would be nice to have Vec<SocketAddr> instead
    hosts: Vec<SocketAddr>,
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#"
        {"hosts": ["172.0.0.1:8000"]}
    "#;
    let doc: Doc = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    dbg!(doc);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:15] doc = Doc {
    hosts: [
        172.0.0.1:8000,
    ],
}
```

Your problem is that `"localhost"` is not a valid `SocketAddr`.